# Can blackberry App World apps run in the background?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-world

I roughly remember blackberry apps being able to run in the background and add itself to a list of startup programs and even add in hooks for various OS events (network event etc) and have a background thread handle these events.

Question
1) Is this true?

2) Are these kind of apps allowed in the app world or only available through enterprise distribution?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes.

2) These kind of apps are allowed if the source is allowed, and the application settings for any special permissions needed are allowed. For example a BES administrator can prevent third party software installation which will prevent all AppWorld applications, and any downloads from the web.